# Memory issues and app crashes caused by Core Graphics

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-graphics, automatic-ref-counting

I have a photo taking app that uses AVFoundation. When a photo is captured, several things are  done like rotating the image, cropping it to the correct size, etc.

The problem though, is that after doing this 3-4 times, the app would finally crash. And during the whole time taking the photos, the NSLog would be receiving memory warnings.

The good news is that I was able to solve this problem last night by using this single code statement: `CGImageRelease(imageRef);`

However, the app is still a little slow at finishing the photo rotation and cropping, Instruments shows that my method implementation for image rotation takes up too much time, and I also want to make sure that there are not any other objects that I should be releasing or setting to nil.

Here is all of the code that runs when the user presses the button to take a photo:

```
-(IBAction)stillImageCapture {


self.imageData = [[NSData alloc]init];

_hasUserTakenAPhoto = @"YES";



AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;

videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;


for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in _stillImageOutput.connections){
    for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]){

        if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo]){

            videoConnection = connection;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (videoConnection) {
        break;
    }
}



[_stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {


    if(imageDataSampleBuffer) {

        self.imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];




        self.image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:self.imageData];



        _subLayer = [CALayer layer];


        if(_inputDevice.position == 2) {



        self.image = [self selfieCorrection:self.image];



            self.image = [self rotate:self.image andOrientation:self.image.imageOrientation];



        } else {



            self.image = [self rotate:self.image andOrientation:self.image.imageOrientation];


        }


        CGFloat widthToHeightRatio = _previewLayer.bounds.size.width / _previewLayer.bounds.size.height;

        CGRect cropRect;
        // Set the crop rect's smaller dimension to match the image's smaller dimension, and
        // scale its other dimension according to the width:height ratio.

        if (self.image.size.width < self.image.size.height) {
            cropRect.size.width = self.image.size.width;
            cropRect.size.height = cropRect.size.width / widthToHeightRatio;
        } else {
            cropRect.size.width = self.image.size.height * widthToHeightRatio;
            cropRect.size.height = self.image.size.height;
        }

        // Center the rect in the longer dimension

        if (cropRect.size.width < cropRect.size.height) {
            cropRect.origin.x = 0;
            cropRect.origin.y = (self.image.size.height - cropRect.size.height)/2.0;


        } else {
            cropRect.origin.x = (self.image.size.width - cropRect.size.width)/2.0;
            cropRect.origin.y = 0;




            float cropValueDoubled = self.image.size.height - cropRect.size.height;


            float final = cropValueDoubled/2;

            //We now have our perfect x coordinate for our crop below.

            finalXValueForCrop = final;

            //The crop is now working perfectly for BOTH selfies and regular photos.

        }



        if(_inputDevice.position == 2) {


        CGRect cropRectFinal = CGRectMake(cropRect.origin.x, finalXValueForCrop, cropRect.size.width, cropRect.size.height);


            CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([self.image CGImage], cropRectFinal);


            _subLayer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef].CGImage;


            CGImageRelease(imageRef);



        } else {



            CGRect cropRectFinal = CGRectMake(cropRect.origin.x, finalXValueForCrop, cropRect.size.width, cropRect.size.height);



            CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([self.image CGImage], cropRectFinal);


            _subLayer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef].CGImage;


            CGImageRelease(imageRef);


            }


        _subLayer.frame = _previewLayer.frame;



        [_takingPhotoView setHidden:YES];


        [_previewLayer addSublayer:_subLayer];


        if ([_hasUserTakenAPhoto isEqual:@"YES"]) {

            //[_takingPhotoView setHidden:YES];
            [_afterPhotoView setHidden:NO];



        }

    }

}];

}
```

Notice how I create the imageRef, and then set it as the sub layer's contents property:

```
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([self.image CGImage], cropRectFinal);

_subLayer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef].CGImage;
```

And then by adding `CGImageRelease(imageRef);` right underneath, it fixed the crashing and memory warnings and memory pressure issues.

However I want to make sure that I am releasing everything that I should be in the above code.

Also, I have 3 different method implementations that all achieve the exact same rotation effect that I need when the image is captured. However, no matter which one I'm using, when I run my app in Instruments with the time profiler, they all have one code statement that is taking up all of the time.

Below are the 3 method implementations, and right above each is the code statement that is causing the lag and taking up all of the time. Hopefully some of you might be able to look at these and tell me how I can fix this.

Method Implementation 1:

Statement taking all of the time: `[self.image drawInRect:(CGRect){0, 0, self.image.size}];`

```
- (UIImage *)normalizedImage {
    if (self.image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) return self.image;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.image.size, NO, self.image.scale);
    [self.image drawInRect:(CGRect){0, 0, self.image.size}];
    UIImage *normalizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return normalizedImage;
}
```

Method Implementation 2:

Statement taking all of the time: `[src drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];`

```
-(UIImage*) rotate:(UIImage*) src andOrientation:(UIImageOrientation)orientation
{

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(src.size);

CGContextRef context=(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

if (orientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {
    CGContextRotateCTM (context, 90/180*M_PI) ;
} else if (orientation == UIImageOrientationLeft) {

    CGContextRotateCTM (context, -90/180*M_PI);
} else if (orientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {

    // NOTHING
} else if (orientation == UIImageOrientationUp) {

    CGContextRotateCTM (context, 90/180*M_PI);
}




[src drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
UIImage *img=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return img;

}
```

Method Implementation 3:

Statement taking all of the time: `CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height), image.CGImage);`

```
- (UIImage *)fixrotation:(UIImage *)image{


    if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) return image;
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    switch (image.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, image.size.width, image.size.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, image.size.width, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI_2);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, image.size.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, -M_PI_2);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
            break;
    }

    switch (image.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, image.size.width, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, image.size.height, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
            break;
    }

    // Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform
    // calculated above.
    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, image.size.width, image.size.height,
                                             CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(image.CGImage), 0,
                                             CGImageGetColorSpace(image.CGImage),
                                             CGImageGetBitmapInfo(image.CGImage));
    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);
    switch (image.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            // Grr...
            CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.height,image.size.width), image.CGImage);
            break;

        default:
            CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height), image.CGImage);
            break;
    }

    // And now we just create a new UIImage from the drawing context
    CGImageRef cgimg = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
    CGContextRelease(ctx);
    CGImageRelease(cgimg);
    return img;

}
```

Comment: Also , are you sure your app crashes because of memory , do you see jettisoned next to stack trace in ASL ?

Comment: Also, have you tried to compress image and then rotate ?